# jquery error on ie9 - ACCESS denied

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, onload, sorttable.js

I am using a sorttable.js script to sort my html table and part of that .js file is-

```
document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)><\/script>");
var script = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == "complete") {
        sorttable.init(); // call the onload handler
    }
};
```

The code works fine in Chrome, while throws error with IE9 `<script id=__ie_onload defer src=javascript:void(0)></script>` --- Access is denied.

```
SCRIPT5: Access is denied.

jquery.js?body=1, line 6275 character 7
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? I did see this: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14081

Comment: I am using jQuery v2.0.3

Comment: Have you tried instead creating the script element, and appending it to the document?

Comment: can you please explain, i am new to this....